# Start Android keyboard in voice recognition mode

Tags: android, voice-recognition

I would like to open the keyboard programmatically and have it start doing voice recognition instantly without the user pressing the mic button.  I know how to implement SpeechRecognizer - that is not what I'm looking for.  I want to start the keyboard VR and text go straight to an editview.  Is this possible?

Comment: What if the user's default keyboard doesn't support voice recognition?

Comment: an issue obviously. If there is a way to test for that I can provide alternative implementation.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no method to start the keyboard in voice recognition mode. I tried for quite some time to get the keyboard to start in number mode with full a-z support as well, but that also proved impossible with the current APIs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible, **but it very much should be**.

I went searching for a way to do this when I needed to use offline speech recognition as a 'hack' - but I couldn't achieve it.

I can only suggest you submit an [AOSP enhancement request](https://code.google.com/p/android/) regarding [InputType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html). The following addition would be helpful:

```
android:inputType="voice"
```

If you place a link to it back here, I'm sure many would star it.

EDIT - [I finally got around to doing it](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=65481)