# How to open Android Keyboard in Speaking mode programmatically?

Tags: android, android-edittext, speech-recognition

I want to **open** the **Android Keyboard** in **Speaking mode** by default programmatically when I focus on editText.

> I know `android:inputType="voice"` is in [**enhancement**](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=65481), is there
>   another way?

I don't want to use [**SpeechRecognizer**](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html) because the difference with the one used by default in Android keyboard is that it works offline.

[image]

Comment: As far as I can see this is not possible, I assume you have seen [Start Android keyboard in voice recognition mode](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19646498/4295238) ?

Comment: Any updates to this?