# Android: Unable to launch "Google Voice Typing" programmatically

Tags: android, keyboard, translation, voice

So, I have this simple application for speech to text translation.

I am using this to launch the google speech to text translator in my activity:

```
val intent = Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH)
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                    RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM)
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault())
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Hi speak something")
startActivityForResult(intent, 1)
```

It launches the following screen - Now this allows me to speak only one sentence at a time but not a continuous speech to text translation
[image]

Instead of this, I want to launch the "google voice typing" keyboard programmatically whenever I want as it allows the continuous speech to text translation.
[image]

I couldn't find any sources to launch "google voice typing" keyboard.

"SwiftKey" keyboard is having a mic button, pressing on it actually launching the "google voice typing" keyboard.

So I am thinking there should be a way to launch "google voice typing" keyboard programmatically.

Comment: check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19570052/start-android-keyboard-in-voice-recognition-mode @Dileep Perla

Comment: @Dhanshri I have checked that already, didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know you cannot programmatically pick a specific Input Method Editor (IME) (e.g. Google Voice Typing) to be used in your application, and you cannot even tag your input fields to demand voice input (see [Start Android keyboard in voice recognition mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19570052/start-android-keyboard-in-voice-recognition-mode)).

SwiftKey itself is an IME, thus it can call something like [setInputMethodAndSubtype](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html#setInputMethodAndSubtype) to change to a different IME.